# Is it possible for a program to use absolutely zero "user" or "system" time?

Tags: process

When timing certain processes, is it possible for either "user" or "system" time to be absolutely zero?

That is, the program does not spend time at all either outside or inside the kernel. Does such program exist?

Comment: no. even the absolutely most minimal program, basically just a `return` would still have SOME overhead for process creation/destruction. Even just the most basic `ret` assembler instruction would incur a few cycles of cpu overhead. The only program which doesn't use up cpu time is a program which isn't running at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way for a program to take Zero Time. Even a one bit change takes a full clock cycle.

I suggest reading [Code by Petzold](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735611319)